# No desktop after using janitor in ubuntu tweak

Tags: unity, launcher, ubuntu-tweak

After using janitor in ubuntu tweak in my ubuntu 13.04 and after restarting there is nothing,no top panel no dock and no left launcher.

Is there any way get them back?

plz help me guy otherwise i have to install ubuntu once again.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/a/17614/44518
Or
https://askubuntu.com/a/202020/44518

This should help you getting this sorted out.